# How can I rotate this ellipse on xy plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, tikz-3dplot

I want to enclose the red circles into an ellipse, but this ellipse should rotate, but the rotation is wrong.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,patterns,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric,angles,quotes,bending,petri,decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta,mindmap,trees}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,polar} %


\tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{50}
%\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{0}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{ffwwqq}{rgb}{1.,0.4,0.}
\definecolor{ccqqqq}{rgb}{0.8,0.,0.}
\definecolor{qqzzqq}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
\definecolor{ffffff}{rgb}{1.,1.,1.}
%\definecolor{DeepPink1}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5, tdplot_main_coords,axis/.style={->},thick]
\draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1, 0, 0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[axis] (0, -1, 0) -- (0, 3, 0) node [right] {$y$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, -1) -- (0, 0, 1) node [above] {$z$};
\draw [color=ffffff,fill=ffffff,fill opacity=1.0] (0.,0.) circle (6.cm);
\fill[fill=black,fill opacity=0.75] (-7.,7.) -- (7,7.) -- (7,-7) -- (-7.,-7) -- cycle;
\fill[white] (0,0,0) circle (6);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=qqzzqq] (-2.5,2.) circle (0.25);
\draw [fill=qqzzqq] (2.5,0.) circle (0.25);
\draw [fill=qqzzqq] (0.,-3.1) circle (0.25);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-1.26,2.84) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-3.74,1.16) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (1.26,-2.84) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (3.74,-1.16) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (1.26,1.16) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (3.74,2.84) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-1.26,-3.36) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (0.5,-5.5) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-0.5,-0.7) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (5.5,0.7) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-4.38,3.46) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-0.62,0.54) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (5.62,-0.54) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-2.5,-1.) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (2.5,-5.2) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (-2.5,5.) circle (0.125);
\draw [fill=ccqqqq] (2.5,0.) circle (0.125);
\end{scriptsize}
\fill[color=ffwwqq,ffwwqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0, -3.1,0) circle [x radius=4, y radius=3, rotate=90];%this ellipse
\fill[color=ffwwqq,ffwwqq,fill opacity=0.1] (2.5,0,0) circle [x radius=3.3, y radius=3.6, rotate=0];
\fill[color=ffwwqq,ffwwqq,fill opacity=0.1] (-2.5,2,0) circle [x radius=2.5, y radius=3.5, rotate=0];
\end{tikzpicture}








\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? If you change `rotate=90` to `rotate=120`, all the red points will be enclosed in some way. Is this not what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you change to \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{0} the ellipse is rotating but not over the plane XY.

Comment: I want rotate this ellipse but keeping z=0, I mean the ellipse must keep over XY plane

Comment: It seems [rotate] refers to screen coordinates.  You can either use a scope with a rotated 3D coordinates, or for 90 degrees  just swap x radius and y radius.